# string length display one character extra - ruby

Tags: ruby, string, encoding, character-encoding

I am processing a csv file uploaded by users, the csv only has one column with the header row "API"

when i process the CSV, for one of the file i see that

```
"API".downcase.length displays 4
```

could it be a encoding issue. when i do `header[0].downcase.bytes` for the string i see

```
[239, 187, 191, 97, 112, 105]
```

when i do "api".bytes i see

```
[97, 112, 105]
```

Any help in understanding why "API".downcase.length in above example display 4 would be really great.

I parse the file like

```
       CSV.foreach(@file_path, headers: true) do |row|
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's possible this could be coming from a [BOM (Byte Order Mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). These are hidden characters that are used to indicate the encoding type of the file. Can you post how you're parsing the CSV file?

Comment: yes, looks like `BOM` when i check using the file `file` command i see that it displays `Unicode text, UTF-8 (with BOM) text,` I have updated the code with how i parse the CSV

Comment: @Zoran is there a way when parsing csv file to ignore `BOM` if present?

Comment: You ought to be able to account for BOM by specifying the encoding, e.g.: `CSV.open(@file_path, 'r:bom|utf-8', headers: true)`.

Comment: @Zoran that does seem to fix the issue, can you please explain a bit more as to what `r:bom|utf-8` does?

Comment: Specifying `r:bom|utf-8` opens the file in read-only mode while also specifying the encoding of the file. If `bom|utf-*` is used, Ruby will check for a Unicode BOM in the input document to help determine the encoding, and if a BOM is found it is stripped out. You can read more about it in Ruby's [IO docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Encoding).

I tested this with a sample CSV file and it seems to be working for me (i.e. the correct header length is being read, confirming the BOM is being stripped). Not entirely sure what else could be the issue here.

Comment: Thanks @Zoran, this fixed the issue. it would be great if you want to convert this to a answer, may be it helps someone. Thanks again

Comment: Glad it could help, posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like in this case the extra character is coming from a [BOM (Byte Order Mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). These are hidden characters that are sometimes used to indicate the encoding type of the file.

One way to handle BOM characters is to specify the `bom|utf-*` encoding when reading the file:

```rb
CSV.open(@file_path, "r:bom|utf-8", headers: true)
```

When `bom|utf-*`is used, Ruby will check for a Unicode BOM in the input document to help determine the encoding, and if a BOM is found it is stripped out - Ruby's [IO docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Encoding) cover this in more detail.